# Trying to display initials in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make this so that when a person types their name just the initials display capitalized and separated by a period. I can't figure out what is wrong with this code I wrote... help pls!

```
def main():

name = input('Type your name and press ENTER. ')
name_list = name.split()

print(name_list)

first = name[0][0]
second = name[1][0]
last = name[2][0]

print(first,'.', second,'.')

main()
```

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or Python 3.x?

Comment: Use `name_list` instead of `name` for starters. You created it for a reason.

Comment: Right on... thanks KEYSER... I feel amazingly dumb now. :P

Comment: Watch out... you are assuming all people have a middle name, and that they only one middle name.  If someone had no middle name or two middle names (or only a first name like Cher or Prince) your code would break.

Answer (score 8):

If you are on Python 2.x you should exchange input for raw_input. Here's a quicker way to achieve what you're aiming for assuming you're on Python 2.x:

```
def main():
    full_name = raw_input('Type your name and press ENTER. ')
    initials = '.'.join(name[0].upper() for name in full_name.split())
    print(initials)
```

Comment: OP said python 3.3. (great answer otherwise!)

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():


    name = input('Type your name and press ENTER. ')
    name_list = name.split()

    print(name_list)

    first = name_list[0][0]
    second = name_list[1][0]
    last = name_list[2][0]

    print(first.upper(),'.', second.upper(),'.', last.upper()) 


main()
```

Comment: I had that before, when I run that using the name "Amanda Leigh Blount" it gives me A . M. A. Which is clearly not the initials.

Comment: @user3534918, I just tested that name, works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version similar to the one you have.
Note that you were using `name` instead of `name_list`, and some hard-coded indexes.

```
def main():

    name = input('Type your name and press ENTER. ')
    name_list = name.split()

    for part in name_list:
        print(part[0].upper() + ". ", end="")
    print()

main()
```

It loops over the list you created with `split()`, and prints the first letter (in upper case) of each part of the name.
The loop only makes sense if you want every part to be included of course.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to explain why it occurred rather than just giving you the solution.

You're using `name` instead of `name_list` when `name_list` is what you're intending to use.

`name` for `'Amanda Leigh Blount' = 'Amanda Leigh Blount'`

but `name_list = name.split() = ['Amanda', 'Leigh', 'Blount']`

---

So you get a difference in the two only on the middle/last name.

The first name is equivalent for both:

`name[0][0] == name_list[0][0]`

The left side matches the first letter of the first letter:

`'Amanda Leigh Blount'[0][0] = 'A'[0] = 'A'`

The right side matches the first letter of the first word.

`['Amanda', 'Leigh', 'Blount'][0][0] = 'Amanda'[0] = 'A'`

---

But for the second:

`name[1][0] != name_list[1][0]`

because the first & second are:

`'Amanda Leigh Blount'[1][0] = 'm'[0] = 'm'`

`['Amanda', 'Leigh', 'Blount'][0][0] = 'Leigh'[0] = 'L'`

So just use `name_list` instead of `name`:

```
first = name_list[0][0]
second = name_list[1][0]
last = name_list[2][0]
```